# Firestore where, orderBy, and onSnapshot not working

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

why is orderBy not working. I can fetch the data with my list of orders. However, if I'll make another order again, the previous list of orders will disappear.

this is the orderCreated at in my firestore
[image]

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = firestore
          .collection("orders")
          .where("userID", "==", currentUser.id)
          .orderBy("orderCreatedAt","desc")
          .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            const arr = [];
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) =>
              arr.push({
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data(),
              })
            );
            setOrders(arr);
           
          });
    
        return () => {
          unsubscribe();
        };
      }, []);
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the `onSnapshot()`? The code you have appears to be correct, what could be happening is that something going wrong while fetching the docs and since the first command of your functions is to create an empty array, maybe that is what is being returned and why your front end shows an empty list.

Comment: @RafaelLemos nothing appears on the screen with "console.log(snapshot"

Comment: if you remove the `orderBy()`, does it work?

Comment: @RafaelLemos yes, it will work if I'll remove the orderBy()

Comment: The only thing I can think of being the cause of this issue is something being wrong in the index of this query, I would recommend you removing the index and creating a new one, you can follows the instructions in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) for that.